# Is there a clever way to use transient object in a singleton?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a builder class which is stateful.

```
interface IFilterBuilder
{
     AddFilter1();
     AddFilter2();
     //etc
     IEnumerable<Filter> FilterList { get; }
}

class FilterBuilder : IFilterBuilder { //implementation }
```

For the moment I'm creating its instances with new keyword because it's short lived and it's used inside a method of a singleton object.

I know I can inject a factory type like `Func<IFilterBuilder>` to singleton and resolve it with the container but I really don't want to have a `filterBuilderFactory`.

Is there a way to do some kind of magic with interception like this:

```
class SingletonClass
{
    [TransientDependency]
    public IFilterBuilder FilterBuilder
    get 
    { 
        //magic.gif
    }
    set
    {
        //some stuff for testability
    }
}
```

So when I need to use it in a method, I get a new instance.

```
IFilter filterBuilder = FilterBuilder;
filterBuilder.AddFilter1();
return filterBuilder.FilterList;
```

It will have to release the object when its out of scope and I should have a way to replace it with a mock in my tests.

Comment: I think it is better to just use filterBuilderFactory than trying to make this work with IOC container.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to store the container somewhere after configuration.
for instance

```
public static class IoC
{
    public static IWindsorContainer Container { get;set; }
}

var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(
    FromAssembly.This()
);
IoC.Container = container;
```

The you can use transients in singleton like this:

```
class SingletonClass
{
    public IFilterBuilder FilterBuilder
    {
        get 
        { 
            return IoC.Container.Resolve<IFilterBuilder>();
        }
    }
}
```

So each time you access FilterBuilder property it will be resolved as you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a proxy object. When implemented manually, it will look like this:

```cs
public class FilterBuilderProxy : IFilterBuilder
{
    private Func<IFilterBuilder> factory;
    public FilterBuilderProxy(Func<IFilterBuilder> factory) 
    { 
        this.factory = factory; 
    }

    AddFilter1() { this.factory.Invoke().AddFilter1(); }
    AddFilter2() { this.factory.Invoke().AddFilter2(); }
    // etc
}
```

Now you can inject this `FilterBuilderProxy` into the singleton and it will ensure that the real transient `IFilterBuilder` implementation is used.

I don't think there's any IoC container that has out of the box support for this, but you can of course use CastleDynamicProxy to generate such class for you for any interface.

Comment: This will create a new instance for each call on the instance. I will lose the state. FilterBuilder keeps a filter list internally, I'm building the list in steps.

Comment: Well, you wanted transient behavior didn't you? You might need to reconsider your design.

Comment: Well, not that transient :). I only need get method of the property rewritten is some way.

Comment: So you don't really want transient :-). In that case you should either use a scoped lifestyle or use a factory in that singleton. Or more the problem to the singleton component; make that component itself transient.